# Issue using VB in access to open up form with OpenForm

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a Inventory form. I want to create an Update button which, when clicked, will open up a new form frm_add-remove, which will contain only the selected inventory item and will allow you to edit the stock quantity. I have listed the click event below, and it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub A_Click()
Dim var As Variant
var = Forms![frm_Inventory]![ItemID]
DoCmd.OpenForm(frm_add-remove, , , "ItemID = " & var, , , )
End Sub
```

and got a compilation error, Expected: expression. ItemID is a column in the frm_Inventory table, as well as in the frm_add-remove table.

I tried with and without the trailing commas. Do I have a syntax error? I thought that you can concatenate with either + or &?

Comment: Do any itemID values have any single or double quotes in them e.g. ' or "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm("frm_add-remove", , , "ItemID = '" & var & "'", , , )
```

I did 2 things.

1. Put `frm_add-remove` in quotes so it gets passed properly as a string and not as a variable name.
2. Put `var` in quotes in case it is also a string.

Comment: Where is the error? The specific line where it occurred should be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: The error is on the DoCmd line (it's not actually yellow, all text on that line turned red). When I changed line to DoCmd.OpenForm ("frm_add-remove") the error went away and the button worked, so the issue must be with the ItemID line...

Comment: Good thinking. Next question: Are you sure ItemID is a field in your `frm_add-remove`'s record source?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. The record source is from a table named tbl_Inventory, and tbl_Inventory has a field ItemID in it.

Comment: Got it. Sometimes VBA doesn't like things in parens. Try taking those out: `DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_add-remove", , , "ItemID = '" & var & "'"`

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error. Do you know when you need parentheses and when not? But one more thing - now I get a runtime error, it says '3021' - no current record. But when I click 'end', it does bring me to the correct page with the correct item name listed...

Comment: The issue was the extra quotes which you thought I should put around 'var'. Since ItemID is numeric, this caused an error. It now works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. No, I don't know for certain why the parens sometimes causes problems. I think they are only needed when assigning a value.  In this case, since you are just running a method, they aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Form name must be a string. Add the missing quotes around it.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm("frm_add-remove", , , "ItemID = " & var )
```

And anything AFTER the last non empty argument is unnecessary (and therefore to remove :)